# C++ Pure virtual method override

Tags: c++, methods, overriding, abstract

I'm facing a little problem and don't know what to do in this situation :
I have this first class (Object3D) which is the Parent class

```
 Object3D{    
    public:
            Object3D(){};
            virtual ~Object3D(){};


///RANDOM METHODS
    virtual void PrintObj() = 0;
    virtual void PrintObj(double) = 0;
//etc..
    private:
//..
    };
```

As you can see , I have the PrintObj() method that is overridden. Some objects take no arguments , like in this child class

```
class Cube : public Object3D
{
    public:
    Cube(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
       ~Cube(){};
    void PrintObj();
    private:
     //..
     };
```

And Other classes require an argument for their call to the PrintObj method

```
class Teapot : public Object3D
    {
    public:
        Teapot(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
        ~Teapot(){};
        void PrintObj(double s){//Code};
    private:
    //..
    };
```

The problem is that these two classes are automatically Abstract they inherit pure virtual methods from the parent class.

I've thought about redefining the PrintObj(double) in the cube class and the PrintObj() class in the Teapot class , but this will allow the user to call the 'wrong' PrintObj() method.

EDIT : I will explain a little bit more what i mean by "calling the wrong" PrintObj();

In the main function I have declared this cube dynamically :

```
Object3D *C = new Cube(250);
```

and this teapot too , dynamically :

```
Object3D *T= new Teapot(250);
```

Now if I change my classes this way :

```
class Cube : public Object3D
{
    public:
        Cube(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
       ~Cube(){};
        void PrintObj();
    private:
        void PrintObj(double){};// i add this method here in private
};
```

and For the Teapot :

```
class Teapot : public Object3D
{
        public:
        Teapot(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
        ~Teapot(){};
        void PrintObj(double s){};

        private:
        void PrintObj(){};//i add this method here in private
};
```

following these changes , in the main function i still can do these calls :

```
C->PrintObj(0);//A cube should be called with no arguments
T->PrintObj();//a teapot should be called only with arguments
```

Which i want to avoid; I can access these methods despite them being private because I declared the object dynamically as an Object3D (I think that's why ?)

Comment: maybe add default value to parameter? or rename one of methods (PrintScaledObj(double)?) ?

Comment: What is the prupose of this `double` ? Should it be a member function ?

Comment: @Hcorg , I've thought about renaming it , but I would rather keep the same scheme to all the classes :/.

Comment: @Jarod42 , Inside the PrintObj(double) method i need to call a function that uses a double argument , but in the PrintObj() method , i don't use that same function , hence the difference.

Comment: @HdjoWattever: Not really clear :-( Whereas I may understand `Object3D::PrintObj()`, which is the `double` in `Object3D::PrintObj(double)` ? scaling, distanceToSomething, captainAge  ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. You need to made second method private.

```
class Cube : public Object3D
{
    public:
    Cube(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
       ~Cube(){};
    void PrintObj();
    private:
     void PrintObj(double d);
     };
```

and

```
class Teapot : public Object3D
    {
    public:
        Teapot(unsigned char c):Object3D(c){};
        ~Teapot(){};
        void PrintObj(double s){//Code};
    private:
        void PrintObj(){//Code};
    //..
    };
```

Comment: Thanks , but doing this still allows me to call the wrong PrintObj() method.
If i declare a Cube C for example , i still can use this bit of code C.PrintObj(1) , which i want to avoid :/.

Comment: You can't, because void PrintObj(double d) is private. You can use this method only inside class body.

Comment: i can do the call , because when i declared my object i did it dynamically this way :

Object3D *C = new Cube(250); // 250 is for the colour;